# Can't install full-text search on existing SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, installation, full-text-search

I installed SQL Server 2008 R2 Express edition before, but forget about full text search. Now I need that feature, so I downloaded installation from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=25174.

When I run installation and install it as new server instance, Full-Text Search feature is enable, but when I try add features to existing server instance this feature isn't available to check. 
Setup folder contains file `sql_fulltext.msi`, so this feature is in the installation.

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled')
```

returns  0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled MS SQL Server, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you would you like to install fulltext search to 2008r2 you have to add advenced services features to it. The easy wey for making this download and install the 'Advanced Services' edition of SQL Server Express 2008r2

If you using Sql Server 2005 then you have too install full version with sp3 edition

Also there you will need to create an index catolg and an index to targeted table

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON SEDA.dbo.F0105TBLSTOKLAR
(
STOKKODU
Language 0X0
)
```

than you can use it like below

USE AdventureWorks2012
GO

```
SELECT Name, ListPrice
FROM Production.Product
WHERE ListPrice = 80.99
   AND CONTAINS(Name, 'Mountain')
GO
```

B. Using FREETEXT to search for words containing specified character values
The following example searches for all documents containing the words related to vital, safety, components.

```
USE AdventureWorks2012
GO

SELECT Title
FROM Production.Document
WHERE FREETEXT (Document, 'vital safety components')
GO
```